# How do I pass a class as an argument to a method?

Tags: java

In the code below I want to pass the 'Races.class' as an argument to the method 'getAllRaces()'. How do I do this?

```
public static void getAllRaces() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    Response myReponse = APIExecutor.getRequest("/races");
    GsonBuilder builder  = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    Races races = gson.fromJson(myReponse.getReqResponse(), Races.class);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the question / issue? Looks like you've already done it....

Comment: All the relevant info is provided by the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I have updated my question. Here i want to pass the 'Races.class' as an argument to the method 'getAllRaces()'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
public static void getAllRaces(Class<?> clazz) {
    ...
    Races races = gson.fromJson(myReponse.getReqResponse(), clazz);
    ...
}
```

You can call it thus:

```
getAllRaces(Races.class)
```

Comment: thanks @dave .This solved my issue

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

`Races.class` as an object of type `Class<Races>`. In your case, you can use a `?` capture to pass a class of unknown type:

```
public static void getAllRaces(Class<?> raceClass) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks  .This solved my issue